Export data from .xps files to a single .xlsx file automatically
PhD student here.
The problem is as follows:
I have thousands of .xps files including specific data, tables and graphs. For data engineering purposes I will need to extract certain data values (string) (not graphs or images) from those files automatically into a single Excel file. I can access the data manually and could copy 'n paste wanted values and varibales but that doesn't make any sense. I will need to make this happen automatically by looping all the files and in a structured manner. Thus python.
What I have drafted so far:
Use PyMuPDF, pandas and openpyxl libraries

Open each OXPS file and pinpoint to wanted data values. I have no idea how to do that in practice. The data .xps is in variables e.g. value1=0.434 value5=0.443 and so on). How to pinpoint exactly to those value1 and value5 and exclude everything else?
Create 'pandas' dataframe from collected data
export it to an excel file

What would be the best approach to this problem? Am I missing something? Help much appreciated. I'm a beginner so bare with me but willing to learn some tricks when it comes to dealing with data sets.
EDIT 28.5.

Final desired look:


Seems like classic text extraction. Would something like this work for you ?

Thanks for the comment. I am getting an error when trying to read the file: File "c:\testing\test\test.py", line 9, in 
with fitz.open(fn) as doc:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymupdf_init_.py", line 2721, in init
raise FileNotFoundError(msg)
pymupdf.FileNotFoundError: no such file: 'C'

So are you saying that I need to list all the filepaths (2000 of them) to that variable?

@Timeless now I had that resolved and seems to be working, of course it is a list and for testing purposes I have it assigned to right files. I get an output excel file. Lets say I have a column with Dog ID and in next cell "5". How would I read and extract that to the file?

If you solved the FileNotFoundError, then you need to delete your new post. Regarding your second question, can you show how looks like the table ? You have to put in a bit of effort ;)

@Timeless Done :) I will edit the question post to show the result as of now. In reality, the value1 and value5 are something else, like "dog ID" and "Dog name" with some more stuff.

I mean the original table in your .xps file, not the resulting .xlsx. If you provide enough (enough) information that describe your .xps and how you expect the final spreadsheet to look like exactly, I'll make sure to provide an answer (or at least a code).

@timeless You should now see the edited question with an example. There are more information besides those that I need to extract, some are strings and some are numbers.

@timeless The way I need to have the final spreadsheet to look like is now edited also into the post.

Your question is a moving target and I'm afraid I can't help you unless you provide a mockup (with some dummy data) of one of your .xps files.

@Timeless If I make it simpler; extract all Dog ID corresponding values from .oxps to excel as described. Would it be easier? Rather than linking them to other metadata.
